# List of all ways to rearrange a string/list

Tags: python, cryptography, combinations, permutation, product

I'm trying to come up with a way to get a list of all possible ways to rearrange a string in order to arrive at a desired string (to ultimately help in cracking columnar transposition ciphers).

For instance, to rearrange "abaca" to "cabaa", you can put the characters at indices 3, 0, 1, 2, 4 of the original string into a new string (in that order). But 3,0,1,4,2 and 3,2,1,0,4 etc... also work.

```
print get_rearrangement_indices("abaca", "cabaa")
>>> [(3, 0, 1, 2, 4), (3, 0, 1, 4, 2), (3, 2, 1, 0, 4), (3, 2, 1, 4, 0), (3, 4, 1, 0, 2), (3, 4, 1, 2, 0)]
```

I want to avoid brute-forcing all possible permutations because when you have a string consisting of "abcdef" and you want to turn it into "fedcba" there's gotta be a smarter way but I'm having a mental block trying to work it out. Here's what I have so far:

```
def get_rearrangement_indices(in_string, out_string):
    old_indices_to_new = {}
    for i, char in enumerate(in_string):
        old_indices_to_new[i] = get_indices_of_element(out_string, char) # where get_indices_of_element("abaca", "a") gives you all the indices where there is an "a" i.e. 0,2,4
    unique_tuples = set([v for k,v in old_indices_to_new.items()])
    new_indices_to_old = defaultdict(tuple)
    for unique_tuple in unique_tuples:
        for k,v in old_indices_to_new.items():
            if not k in new_indices_to_old[v]:
                new_indices_to_old[v] += (k,)
    print old_indices_to_new                   # {0: (1, 3, 4), 1: (2,), 2: (1, 3, 4), 3: (0,), 4: (1, 3, 4)}
    old_indices_to_new = {v:k for k,v in new_indices_to_old.items()} # Can't decide if this or the old one is easier to work with
    print old_indices_to_new                   # {(3,): (0,), (0, 2, 4): (1, 3, 4), (1,): (2,)}
    # itertools
    # ???
    return profit
```

Comment: Don't know, but remember you can use list comprehension `[i for i, x in enumerate(out_string) if x == element]` instead of `get_indices_of_element()` for simplicitiy's sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could permute each letter's indices separately.

```
from itertools import permutations, product
from collections import defaultdict

def get_rearrangement_indices(in_string, out_string):
    indices = defaultdict(list)
    for i, c in enumerate(in_string):
        indices[c].append(i)
    for perms in product(*map(permutations, indices.values())):
        inds = {c: iter(p) for c, p in zip(indices, perms)}
        yield tuple(next(inds[c]) for c in out_string)
```

Demos:

```
>>> list(get_rearrangement_indices("abaca", "cabaa"))
[(3, 0, 1, 2, 4), (3, 0, 1, 4, 2), (3, 2, 1, 0, 4), (3, 2, 1, 4, 0), (3, 4, 1, 0, 2), (3, 4, 1, 2, 0)]

>>> list(get_rearrangement_indices("aabb", "abab"))
[(0, 2, 1, 3), (0, 3, 1, 2), (1, 2, 0, 3), (1, 3, 0, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like:

1. Build a positions dictionary for both source and output. Positions dictionary maps each character to the list of indices at which this character is found in the string.
2. Build all the allowed transformations. An allowed transformation for a character is:

   a) if this character is unique within the string (its positions count is 1), its source index is unambiguously mapped to that of the output;

   b) if this character is found more than once then build all the permutations of its output dict positions and place them in the list according to the source dict.

The resulting list is thus a direct product of a few subspaces.

For instance, string 'ann' can be converted to 'nan' as:

source dict is {'a': [0], 'n': [1, 2]}
output dict is {'a': [1], 'n': [0, 2]}

```
Then for each character in the source keys
   for each permutation of its output value list
      create a list with this permutation spread across the indices from the source value
```

permutations are
'a' -> [1]
'n' -> [0, 2], [2, 0]

The resulting product is

[1] placed at positions [0]; [0, 2] placed at [1, 2] --> [1, 0, 2]
[1] placed at positions [0]; [2, 0] placed at [1, 2] --> [1, 2, 0]